# Cleaning up the AppEngine BlobStore

Tags: google-app-engine, go

My AppEngine server has a lot of orphaned blobs not used in the BlobStore.  I'd like to write code to iterate over all the blobs and check if they are not being used and then delete.  I can't find a way to iterate over the BlobStore.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a blobstore viewer so you can at least see them?

Comment: In the AppEngine dashboard it shows you a list of stuff.  But it doesn't tell you what is being used or not.   So that's why I need to write a piece of code to iterate over them all and do some data store queries to check if they are being used... but first I need to iterate.

Comment: Where is the list of blobs found in the dashboard?

Comment: In the old interview under "Blob Viewer."  Doesn't look like the new interface has it.  https://appengine.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/reference#BlobInfo via a datastore query (though such query is eventually consistent).

Comment: From that page: `NOTE: The Files API was deprecated on June 11, 2013 (v1.8.1) and will be shut down soon, at which point these functions will no longer work. Use Google Cloud Storage instead (https://cloud.google.com/storage/).`

Comment: I guess that's why Google is making it hard to work with the Blobstore.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Here is some GQL that works: "SELECT * FROM __BlobInfo__"  <-- sorry doesn't display right but add 3 underscores before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code solution for iterating over blobs in golang:

```
c.Infof("Iterating over blobs")
q := datastore.NewQuery("__BlobInfo__")

// Iterate over the results.
total := 0
t := q.Run(c)
for {
        var bi blobstore.BlobInfo
        _, err := t.Next(&bi)
        if err == datastore.Done {
                break
        }
        if err != nil && isErrFieldMismatch(err) == false {
                c.Errorf("Error fetching next Blob: %v", err)
                break
        }
        // Do something with the Blob bi
        c.Infof("Got blob [%v] of size [%v]", bi.ContentType, bi.Size)
        total++
        if total > 100 { break }
}
c.Infof("Iterating Done")
```

You'll also need to use this function to ignore field mismatch errors:

```
func isErrFieldMismatch(err error) bool {
    _, ok := err.(*datastore.ErrFieldMismatch)
    return ok
```

}